# Paramiko, Python, Windows : How to connect to a remote computer and from there to a NAS using SSH

Tags: python, windows, paramiko

I've seen several questions and answers related to this topic but I've been unable to grasp the howto.

1. What I'm able to do : connect to a remote computer using a Python script using Paramiko and return information, for instance, to ping a switch :

   > > ssh = pk.SSHClient()
   > >
   > > ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(pk.AutoAddPolicy())
   > >
   > > ssh.connect('{}'.format(IP), port=xxx, username='xxx',password='xxx')
   > >
   > > stdin, stdout, stderr = \
   > >
   > > ssh.exec_command('ping -n 1 xxx.xxx.x.x\n')
   > >
   > > print('Ping switch: \n', stdout.readlines())
2. What I would like to do but don't know how to : connect once to the computer and then using SSH (paramiko.SSHClient()) again connect to another device (in this case a NAS) and 'exec_command', something like :

   > > ssh = pk.SSHClient()
   > >
   > > ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(pk.AutoAddPolicy())
   > >
   > > ssh.connect('{}'.format(IP), port=xxx, username='xxx',password='xxx') # connect to computer
   > >
   > > ssh.connect('{}'.format(IP), port=xxx, username='xxx',password='xxx') #connect to NAS  from computer
   > >
   > > stdin, stdout, stderr = \
   > >
   > > ssh.exec_command('shutdown\n, y\n') # send command to NAS
   > >
   > > print('Ping switch: \n', stdout.readlines())

[image]

Is this possible, does anyone know a way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open a tunnel, check [paramiko demo](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/forward.py) or use `sshtunnel` package.
For the latter:

```
import paramiko as pk
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    remote_computer_ip,
    ssh_username=remote_username,
    ssh_password=remote_password,
    remote_bind_address=(NAS_IP, 22),
    debug_level='DEBUG',
) as tunnel:
    ssh = pk.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(pk.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(NAS_IP,
                port=tunnel.local_bind_port,  # redirected to port NAS_IP:22
                username=NAS_USER,
                password=NAS_PASS)
    (stdin, stdout, stderr) = ssh.exec_command(...)   # your stuff
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried but I get the error :

_Could not connect to gateway: (remote_host IP) ((10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))_

I added the port for the remote_computer but the error persists.

Comment: error is just saying it cannot reach remote_host IP, doublecheck enabling verbose output (see edit above).

Comment: Here's the 1st part _2016-05-23 13:24:00,997 | INFO    | Skipping loading of ssh config file
2016-05-23 13:24:01,013 | INFO    | 0 keys loaded from agent
2016-05-23 13:24:01,044 | INFO    | Connecting to gateway: xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx as user 'xxxxx'
2016-05-23 13:24:01,044 | DEBUG   | Concurrent connections allowed: True
2016-05-23 13:24:01,044 | DEBUG   | Logging in with password ***********
2016-05-23 13:24:07,081 | INFO    | Opening tunnel: 0.0.0.0:65496 <> 192.168.0.2:22
2016-05-23 13:24:28,125 | INFO    | Closing all open connections..._

Comment: and the second _2016-05-23 13:24:28,125 | DEBUG   | Open local addresses: 0.0.0.0:65496
2016-05-23 13:24:28,125 | INFO    | Shutting down tunnel 0.0.0.0:65496
2016-05-23 13:24:28,156 | INFO    | Tunnel: 0.0.0.0:65496 <> IPNAS:22 is closed
2016-05-23 13:24:28,156 | DEBUG   | Transport is closed
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond_

Comment: I had to change the code to :

`('{}'.format(IP), PORT)`

in the sshtunnel.open_tunnel configuration.

Comment: https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest claims that the package is not supported on Windows

Comment: @8bitjunkie it IS supported in windows. The description is indeed misleading, since it refers to another package which is not...

Answer (score -1):

You could ask the question in a more simpler way. If I am not wrong are you trying to connect to one machine using paramiko and from that machine you want to connect to NAS machine?

Or is that you connect to 1 machine say A and then you want the ssh handle of that machine and connect to NAS machine and generate another ssh handle?

If latter is the case, I would suggest you to use a class and create an object for every ssh connect.
You can have a look at this:

[ssh.py](https://github.com/Prince88/ssh/blob/master/ssh.py)

Comment: Do you really want a paramiko connection from Remote computer to NAS? If no, then directly execute the command on NAS using paramiko handle using (ssh <user@ip> <command>) but for this you will need to have the ssh keys already stored on your remote machine. Alternatively you can have a script saved on the remote machine(which will connect to NAS and run commands) and you can invoke that script using remote machine handle

Comment: Would you possibly have an example of : ssh <user@ip> <command>, for instance in the code snippet above?